# Can't get function triggered in printed list

Tags: jquery, function, onclick

I created a program which prints out a list from an SQL database.  So far, so good.  I can print out the list.  However, recently I tried to add an "X" to each item printed out.  Eventually this would turn into a system by which the user could delete the item by clicking the X, but I wanted to do this with baby steps.  So, I've been trying to make it so that when the user clicks one of these 'X'es, it prints "hello" to the console before I do anything fancy.  This, however, does not work.

I've tried writing this two ways.  When I do it this way:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS & JS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload = "showList()">

<ol></ol>

  <script type="text/javascript">


    function showList(){


      $.get("/api/toDoList", function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
        {
          $("ol").append("<li>" + data[i] + "<span id ='" + i + "'>X</span>" + "</li>");
    }



      });
    };

 $("span").click(function(){
  console.log("Hello!");
});
 //why doesn't this work, or putting an onclick function the span!?
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

it simply does nothing.

When I do it this way:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS & JS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload = "showList()">

<ol></ol>

  <script type="text/javascript">


    function showList(){


      $.get("/api/toDoList", function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
        {
          $("ol").append("<li>" + data[i] + "<span id ='" + i + "' onclick = 'delete()'>X</span>" + "</li>");
    }



      });
    };

function delete(){
  console.log("Hello!");
}

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get an error which says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token delete."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem with your first fragment of code.**

It did nothing because you were attaching the click event:

`$("span").click(function(){
  console.log("Hello!");
});`

outside the asynchronous call, meaning the event was attached to `span` elements that weren't in the DOM yet since the call had not finished yet.

In cases you want to attach events to elements that will be added to the DOM in the future but are not there yet, use delegated events, like this:

```
//the 'ol' is in the DOM since the beginning, so the event is attached fine,
//then you pass the actual element you want the event to be triggered on, as a
//second parameter, in this case 'span'
//this way, it does not matter when 'span's are added to the 'ol', the event
//will always work on them
$('ol').on('click', 'span', function(){

});
```

**Problem with your second fragment of code.**

This approach works fine because the handler is in-lined with the HTML code but it's not recommended anymore to do this, so I advise you to go with the alternative I provide in my snippet. The error you are getting is, as already mentioned by Hien Nguyen, because `delete` is a reserved word in JS, so you can't use it as function name.

HIH

```js
function showList(){
  //$.get("/api/toDoList", function(data) {
    //console.log(data);
    let data = ['d1', 'd2', 'd3']; //this is just test data because I can't access '/api/toDoList' (duh)
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      $("ol").append("<li>" + data[i] + " <span id ='" + i + "'>X</span>" + "</li>");
    }

  //});
};

    $('ol').on('click', 'span', function(){
        console.log("Hello! " + $(this).parent().text());
    });

showList();
```

```css
span{
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<!--<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
-->

<ol></ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `delete` is reserved keyword, you can not set function name `delete`, you can change name to another name like delete1

```js
   function showList(){


      $.get("/api/toDoList", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        data = [1,2,3];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
        {
          $("ol").append("<li>" + data[i] + "<span id ='" + i + "' onclick = 'delete1()'>X</span>" + "</li>");
    }



      });
    };

function delete1(){
  console.log("Hello!");
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS & JS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload = "showList()">

<ol></ol>

  
</body>
</html>
```